# Complex Gerund Usage

Tags: gerunds, to-infinitive

there is a sentence formation that didn't sit with me well.

***Between counseling and having to repeat my courses in summer school. It is a toss-up.***

I assume having to repeat part is not a complex infinitive such as "i am delighted to have met him."

Comment: What is your question? Do you want a re-write? To know if it is a correct sentence? To know if there is an alternative? Something else?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It may be an ungainly sentence, but it is grammatical. What it means is

> I am undecided between counseling and repeating my courses in summer school.

If you feel compelled to use the “have to verb” construction, which is perfectly grammatical but not obviously needed in this case, I’d make the sentence easier to parse by using a parallel structure.

> I am undecided between having to get counseling or having to repeat my courses in summer school.

That last version should eliminate whatever was causing you unease with the sentence you asked about, but it seems unnecessarily verbose to me.

Comment: No. Did you notice there's a period in the middle? "*Between counseling and having to repeat my courses in summer school*" is not a sentence.

Comment: The second explanation perfectly fits now. I figured out "have to" was used in gerund form. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Punctuation is not grammar. Nor was the question about punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not grammatical because the first sentence is not a complete sentence. It has neither a subject nor a conjugated verb. It's just a prepositional phrase.

It would be correct if the period were changed to a comma:

> Between counseling and having to repeat my courses in summer school, it is a toss-up.

Comment: Right, but I was just trying to figure out the usage of having to verb. I did not focus on if the sentence was grammatically correct. I first thought the process of going to summer school took place in the past in a progressive way and my question was to understand why "having repeated" was not used.

Comment: Then please explain all of that clearly in your question. Answering this question was a waste of my time because you didn't ask for what you wanted